# Why is `(a) read as a list while `(a b) isn't?

Tags: list, clojure, lisp, cons

While learning clojure, I was very surprised to find out that these two objects are different types:

```
(list? `(inc))   ;; true
(list? `(inc 1)) ;; false
```

In theory, I understand why the second form returns false, that object
is actually a `clojure.lang.Cons`. In practice, though, I don't
understand why **that** is happening.

Why does the reader read `` `(inc) `` different from `` `(inc 1) ``? What is happening under the hood?

Comment: It doesn't relate to inc, compare `(list? \`(a))` with `(list? \`(a b))`. Anyway, `(type ..)` reveals the first is a PersistentList, the second is a Cons. But the why .. no idea.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, in the other lisps I know when the cons' second value is `nil` it is a one-element list (i.e. `(inc)`). Is that different in clojure?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `(type \`(a b c))` also results in Cons. It is only the `\`(singular)` form that appears different and is read as a PersistentList.

Comment: @user2864740, indeed; I just learned something there.

Comment: `(list? '(a b))` returns `true`. I'm assuming that the syntax quote doesn't return a list because it's easier to implement `~@` splicing with general seqs (with `concat` or something). It would probably make more sense to check for `seq?` instead of `list?`.

Comment: @DaoWen Possibly. I need a predicate to match quoted lists or code, but not any other collection. Is that `seq?`? I know it checks for `ISeq`, but I don't whether any other collections implement `ISeq`. (in any case, that's a side topic, I'm still curious about the question)

Comment: This is interesting: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cons#example-54f820aee4b0b716de7a6530. Anyway, you should probably just roll out your own predicate; e.g.: `(defn code? [x] (or (list? x) (instance? clojure.lang.Cons x)))`

Comment: @DaoWen Yes, [that's what I'm doing](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/cider-nrepl/blob/debug/src/cider/nrepl/middleware/util/instrument.clj#L38), but the question was bugging me :-). And that link actually helps quite a bit.

Comment: According to http://insideclojure.org/2015/01/02/sequences/ `clojure.lang.PersistentList` is the only collection that implements `ISeq` and will be true for `seq?`. (At bottom, starting just above "Predicates and functions.")

Comment: @ShannonSeverance That's odd. I'm getting that ```(seq? `(x y))``` is true and ```(list? `(x y))``` is false. Which I _think_ contradicts that.

Comment: I don't think `clojure.lang.Cons` are considered collections, and it does implement `ISeq`.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance But it returns true on `coll?` :-\

Comment: Apparently I was wrong. Effing Clojure.

Comment: from that link "seq? - checks whether an instance implements ISeq"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the reader encounters a syntax-quoted form, that turns out to be a collection, it will [iterate over each element and call syntax-quote recursively](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/201a0dd9701e1a0ee3998431241388eb4a854ebf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L862). The result is `cons`ed, beginning with `nil`.

So it comes down to the question why the following holds:

```
> (list? (cons 'inc nil))
true
> (list? (cons 'inc (cons 1 nil)))
false
```

This seems to be a matter of definition.

Answer (score 2):

`list?` is actually a function of very limited usefulness. In fact I have yet to see Clojure code that used `list?` without it being at best a poor choice, more often the cause of a bug.

If you want to know if something is "listy", `seq?` is a great choice.

in action:

```
user=> (pprint/print-table (for [item [[] () `(a) `(a b) (seq [1])]]
                              {'item (pr-str item)
                               'seq? (seq? item)
                               'list? (list? item)
                               'type (type item)}))
|            item |  seq? | list? |                                           type |
|-----------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------|
|              [] | false | false |            class clojure.lang.PersistentVector |
|              () |  true |  true |    class clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList |
|        (user/a) |  true |  true |              class clojure.lang.PersistentList |
| (user/a user/b) |  true | false |                        class clojure.lang.Cons |
|             (1) |  true | false | class clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq |
```

Comment: The trouble is that vectors are schizophrenic: They say they are associative, but they provide a sequence of values, not of key-value pairs, under `seq`.

Comment: They also say that they are `seqential?` though.

Comment: I see that `clojure.lang.Sequential` is empty - so types simply elect to implement it. Nevertheless, is `sequential?` better than `seq?` here, as an improvement upon `list?`?

Comment: I think the asker would have to answer that. I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that they wanted "listy" things, eg. things that would print with () and conj to the front.